# Not able to create Enums inside Generic Class?

Tags: c#

A very silly question...

I am trying to make a generic class like the below

```
public static class Component<TClass>where TClass : class
    {
        public static void Method<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IComparable, IFormattable
        {
            if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("TEnum must be an enum.");
            }
            if (myEnum.Equals(DependencyLifecycle.SingleInstance)) 
            {
                //do some thingh
            }
        }  
    }

    public enum DependencyLifecycle
    {
        SingleInstance,
        DoubleInstance
    };
```

and trying to invoke it as

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConsoleApplication1.Component<Program>.Method<DependencyLifecycle.SingleInstance>();
        }
    }
```

but I am not properly able to do it.

**Errors**

```
Error   1   'ConsoleApplication1.DependencyLifecycle.SingleInstance' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type' 

Error   2   Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Type' and 'ConsoleApplication1.DependencyLifecycle'
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "I am not properly able to do it." We would like to know what errors you are getting, what is happening when you are trying to create the Enums, and what is suppose to happen.

Comment: Error 1 'ConsoleApplication1.DependencyLifecycle.SingleInstance' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type' 
Error 2 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Type' and 'ConsoleApplication1.DependencyLifecycle'

Comment: It's not clear why you are using generics here or what you are trying to accomplish. Yes, we see the compilation error, but without knowing what your intent is, it's not straight forward to recommend how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't provide a *value* of an enum as a type parameter. You'll need it to be an actual parameter. You want something like this.

```
    public static void Method<TEnum>(TEnum myEnum) 
        where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IComparable, IFormattable
    {
        if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("TEnum must be an enum.");
        }
        if ((DependencyLifecycle)myEnum== DependencyLifecycle.SingleInstance)
        {
            //do some thingh
        }
    }
```

Called:

```
ConsoleApplication1.Component<Program>.Method(DependencyLifecycle.SingleInstance);
```

(if it doesn't infer the type, this way:)

```
ConsoleApplication1.Component<Program>.Method<DependencyLifecycle>(DependencyLifecycle.SingleInstance);
```

Comment: only this change if (myEnum.Equals(DependencyLifecycle.SingleInstance))

Answer (score 2):

As the error clearly states, you are trying to compare the enum type to a field value. Your enum type here is DependencyLifecycle and your field is DependencyLifecycle.SingleInstance.

If you are trying to check if it is of type DependencyLifecycle then you can do this

```
if (typeof(TEnum) == typeof(DependencyLifecycle))
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Would `GetType` also work in this situation? Like `if (typeof(TEnum) == DependencyLifecycle.GetType())`?

Comment: This being an enum, it does not have a method called GetType()

Answer (score -1):

This kind of meta-programming is not really common in C# (because there is always a better way to do it), but this probably comes closest to what you want:

```
public static class Component
{
    public static void Method<TEnum>() where TEnum : DependencyLifecycle
    {
        if (typeof(TEnum) == typeof(SingleInstanceDependencyLifecycle))
        {
            // do something with SingleInstance
        }
    }
}

public abstract class DependencyLifecycle { }
public sealed class SingleInstanceDependencyLifecycle : DependencyLifecycle { }
public sealed class DoubleInstanceDependencyLifecycle : DependencyLifecycle { }
```